# Google Analytics Reporting API (UA) for GA360 account limit 10000 rows?

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm using Google Analytics Reporting API (UA vs4) for a GA 360 client and getting up to 10,000 rows per API call.
Pagination (with pageToken) is used, but it doesn't help to get around this limit. The maximum number of rows retrieved is always 10,000.
The email address to access the API is added as a Viewer (not as Analytics).
I do not encounter this problem with other websites.

How to overcome this limit? Is it a GA 360 setting?

The pagination code part:

```
response = get_report(analytics, date_start, date_end)
pageToken = response['reports'][0].get('nextPageToken')
df = df_response(response)

while pageToken != None:

    response = get_report(analytics, date_start, date_end, pageToken)
    pageToken = response['reports'][0].get('nextPageToken')
    df_temp = df_response(response)
    df = pd.concat([df, df_temp], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

The output as generated with pageSize is 50,000:

[image]

This pageToken clips, strangely enough, already at 10,000.

If I do this for another website it shows the expected pageToken is 50,000 and continues to retrieve all data:

[image]

**Problem is with and without clientID**. Without clientID this is the output:
[image]

Same code, same set with clientID clips at 10000 rows:
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code. i need to see the call you are making to the api

Comment: See the pagination code. Please let me know of you need more code (all is a bit too difficult because it uses classes/functions, etc.).

Comment: is that python?

Comment: Yes indeed Python

Answer (score 1):

When you send a request to Google analytics for your report. You can set the pagesize to up to 100k.   You probably have it set to 10k currently.

[image]

Comment: @DalmTo thank you for your reply. I have set the pageSize to 100k but still encounter the limit of 10,000 rows. It is strange that it occurs only with a particular website and not with others. Do you have another idea?

Comment: The thing is as far as i know its always been a limit of 10k yet the docs say that it should be 100k let me reach out to the team for clarification.

Comment: Can you check that there is a next page for your 10k its not just that there are no more rows right?

Comment: Indeed, there should be much more rows. But after 10k it stops. See part of the output that I generate in the question.

Comment: I will let you know when i hear back from the team.

Comment: hmm I got a thank you From the team and nothing more.   I'm going to have to ask for clarification tomorrow 

Comment: Thank you for your support DalmTo! Do you already got an update from the team?

Comment: They say the images you are showing show that the request you are making only has 10k records.    You need to make a request that will return more rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244872/discussion-between-henry-and-daimto).

Comment: @DalmTo, I found the reason for the max of 10000 rows: if the dimension clientID is included, it haa a max of 10000. If this is not included, there is no 'clipping'. This looks like a bug. Can you please report this to the team or let me know how I can get in contact with them?

Comment: the team says your getting 10k rows because that's the amount of data available for the request you are making.     There's no limit on clientId its just returning the results for the request you are making.

Comment: See the added screenshots: it is. Occuring at a GA 360 account.

Comment: you have a 360 account why not contact them directly?  support is one of the features of having a 360 account.

Comment: I am doing this for a client with a 360 account but that would be a good idea.

Comment: Your client should be able to get you a contact email to just ask.   My contacts are API related / dev team.  Getting a contact directly though 360 will get you help specifically on your clients account.

Comment: Thank you @DalmTo for your support and suggestions.